# liferea: change default link color

Tags: theme, rss-aggregator

Liferea (Linux Feed Reader) uses per default a dark blue color for hyperlinks. I am using a dark desktop theme (white text on dark background) and these default colors are very difficult to read.

I am wondering whether there is a way to change the default color to something else, presumably by editing some `.css` file as can be done in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the source tree for Liferea there's a file, `css/liferea.css`, which contains the customization that you're asking about.

- https://github.com/lwindolf/liferea/blob/master/css/liferea.css

There's a section of this file:

```
   Color Definitions:
   ==================

   To allow using GTK theme colors the following key words 
   will be replaced with the corresponding GTK theme color values:
...
...
   GTK-COLOR-TEXT
   GTK-COLOR-NORMAL-LINK
   GTK-COLOR-VISITED-LINK
 */

body {
    background: #GTK-COLOR-BASE;
    color: #GTK-COLOR-TEXT;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

blockquote {
        border-left: 2px solid #GTK-COLOR-DARK;
        background: #GTK-COLOR-BG;
        padding: 5px;
        font-style: italic;
        margin: 5px 20px;
    clear:both;
}

a {
    color: #GTK-COLOR-NORMAL-LINK;
}

a:visited {
    color: #GTK-COLOR-VISITED-LINK;
}
```

Within this file you could change the colors for the `a` and `a:visited` sections, overriding these settings to what ever color you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace basic forground, background & link if you like, eg:

`~/.config/liferea/liferea.css`

```
/* inkpot theme */
body {
    background: #1e1e27;
    color: #cfbfad;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

a {
    color: #8b8bff;
}

a:visited {
    color: #737dd5;
}

::selection {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
```